# Error estimate for Midpoint rule of ratio of integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Let's say that I partition an interval $[a,b]$
such that $x_{0} = a$, $x_{k} = a + k\Delta$, until $x_{K} = b$

$\Delta$ is the length of the subinterval. I assume equal length, and thus $\Delta = \frac{b-a}{K}$

I have the ratio of integrals as follow. We have the same function in numerator and denominator, but I am simply evaluation the definite interval at different intervals. The numerator is evaluated at a partition $k$ and the denominator evaluated at the interval $[a,b]$.

$\frac{\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_{k}} f(s) ds}{\sum_{h=1}^{K}\int_{x_{h-1}}^{x_{h}} f(s) ds}$

Now I approximate using say the midpoint rule

$\frac{f(\frac{x_{k-1}+x_{k}}{2})\Delta}{\sum_{h=1}^{K} f(\frac{x_{h-1}+x_{h}}{2}) \Delta}$

I know $\Delta$ drops out for equal length of partitions, but let's keep it.

Now I want to look at the error estimate of my approximation

I have that the error for the $k$ partition is

$E_{k} = \left|\frac{\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_{k}} f(s) ds}{\sum_{h=1}^{K}\int_{x_{h-1}}^{x_{h}} f(s) ds} - \frac{f(\frac{x_{k-1}+x_{k}}{2})\Delta}{\sum_{h=1}^{K} f(\frac{x_{h-1}+x_{h}}{2}) \Delta} \right|$

Is this simply a work of messy algebra?

I believe I can write $\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_{k}} f(s) ds = f(\frac{x_{k-1}+x_{k}}{2})\Delta + \frac{\Delta^{3}M}{24}$

where $|f^{''}(\xi)| \leq M$

and the bottom as

$\sum_{h=1}^{K}\int_{x_{h-1}}^{x_{h}} f(s) ds = \sum_{h=1}^{K} f(\frac{x_{h-1}+x_{h}}{2}) \Delta + \sum_{h=1}^{K} \frac{\Delta^{3}M}{24}$

Doing the algebra, I can calculate $E_{K}$, but I prefer to simplify and bound it such that I find a $N$ so that $|E_{k}| \leq N$

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Consider $f(x,y) = x/y$ for $y\ne 0$. If $|y| \ge c^{-1} > 0$, then you have
$$ \| f'(x,y) \| = \| (y^{-1}, xy^{-2}) \| \le c^2 \| (x,y) \| $$
and
$$ |f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y) - f(x,y)| \le c^2 (\| (x,y) \| + \|(\Delta x, \Delta y)\|) \| (\Delta x, \Delta y)\| $$
for $|y + \Delta y| \ge c^{-1}$.

Comment: By |(x,y)| you mean manhattan norm?

Comment: I used the euclidean norm. But it doesn't really matter.